# _viewControllerForSupportedInterfaceOrientationsWithDismissCheck Unrecognised selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am present an image on a final view controller (portait), at the point everything is on screen, if I turn the device landscape, and landscaperight, it still is ok, however;

IF I then use SLComposeViewController (for Twitter posting) once I dismiss that (be it cancel or posted something) then rotate the phone landscape, the app crashes with the following error;

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[_UIAppearanceCustomizableClassInfo
>   _viewControllerForSupportedInterfaceOrientationsWithDismissCheck:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b9eefd0'

Whilst I do not use landscape mode, the app does turn when I turn it landscape orientation, but that's not the major issue, the issue is the app crashing.

Whilst I know it will be fine if the user doesn't turn the phone after posting to Twitter, it's not ideal, and something i'd rather fix as I am sure you agree.

Regarding orientation support, the AppDelegate.m has this;

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait |UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

And the controller that crashes has this;

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSString *viewControllerClassName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:object_getClassName(window.rootViewController)];
    if ([viewControllerClassName isEqualToString:@"_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController"])   {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I have the similar exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteValue _viewControllerForSupportedInterfaceOrientationsWithDismissCheck:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e40260'  ..  ((

Answer (score 4):

I also saw similar crash in iOS 8 when you present Modal View Controller from UIActionSheet and you dismissed the Modal View Controller and rotate the screen.

I think it had to do with presenting modal view controller. The above fix for delaying the presentation of modal view controller definitely works,

Instead of calling present Modal View controller from actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:  delegate method of UIActionSheet , calling from " actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:" and works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing a similar issue on iOS8, with the app crashing after a modal view controller was dismissed and the phone was subsequently rotated.

In my case the modal view controller was being presented from an action sheet in the actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex: method. The workaround I found was to move the code that presented the modal view controller out of that method into a new method and calling it asynchronously, i.e. `[self performSelector:@selector(presentModalViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];`

Not sure why that would make a difference, but it does let the action sheet animate out before the modal view controller is presented, which may have some effect.

Comment: Hi Daniel, interesting... I found a temporary workaround by using TWTweetComposer which I know is outdated, but oddly, it did not crash when using that, yet crashed when using the SLComposeViewController - strange as the latter is an Apple framework!

Comment: In the same app, I'm using SLComposeViewController without issue (even presented from an actionsheet).

Comment: I just noticed that your method signature for the view controller is `-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window`. Should be simply `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` I think. Whether that would cause the issue you reported though, I'd be doubtful, but looks like at root it's an iOS8 bug, so hard to know.