# _viewControllerForSupportedInterfaceOrientationsWithDismissCheck exception under iOS 8

Tags: iphone, exception, ios8

The application for iOS 7 works fine but under iOS 8 I got

```
  [someObj _viewControllerForSupportedInterfaceOrientationsWithDismissCheck:]: 
                                     unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

when I rotate my iPhone..

What is may be wrong?

Stack trace from a simulator:

```
       *** First throw call stack:
           (
        ...
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x030ffa97 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x03c84a75 -[NSObject(NSObject)      doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x03bcd9c7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x03bcd58e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
        5   UIKit                               0x01b3ea90 -[UIWindow _shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:checkForDismissal:isRotationDisabled:] + 164
        6   UIKit                               0x01b3ef73 -[UIWindow _shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] + 82
        7   UIKit                               0x01b4012d __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 69
        9   UIKit                               0x01b40988 -[UIWindow _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientation:] + 1397
        10  UIKit                               0x01b4040c -[UIWindow _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientationIfRotationEnabled:] + 93
        11  UIKit                               0x01b3feab -[UIWindow _handleDeviceOrientationChange:] + 122
        12  Foundation                          0x02cae929 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 40
        13  CoreFoundation                      0x03c47974 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
        ...
        20  GraphicsServices                    0x049c5c8b _PurpleEventCallback + 765
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x03ba0a65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
        23  CoreFoundation                      0x03ba09ce __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 510
       .......
     )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100437

Comment: I tried but it did not help

Comment: Can you add the code that is calling that selector?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIViewControllerOneToOneTransitionContext _viewControllerForSupportedInterfaceOrientationsWithDismissCheck:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b785170'

Comment: But this first object may be different (not _UIViewControllerOneToOneTransitionContext).. every time it's different

Comment: do you try [it](https://translate.google.ru/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.changyy.org%2F2014%2F10%2Fios-viewcontrollerforsupportedinterface.html)?

Comment: Thanks..I did not understand what is written in the solution part)

Answer (score 0):

Are you presenting a modal in reaction to user touching action sheet buttons?

Try using this delegate method
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

instead of 
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

It looks like the action sheet is its own window on iOS 8.  If you present a modal before the action sheet is fully gone, it winds up being referenced by the action sheet window.

Later when the device rotates, it probably tries to pass on the rotation event, but the modal has long since been replaced by another object (which is not a view controller subclass), so you get this crash.

The same may be true for alert views since the docs say they share implementations in iOS 8.

Comment: I just open a new screen(UITableViewController) then try to edit data in the text field and after that press 'Back' ([self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]) and got [__NSArrayI or NCFString _viewController..]:un. selector.. with a breakpoint somewhere inside iOS libs(not my code). On iOS7 - everyting's fine.